# Django trigger parent model save when editing inline in admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model (Parent) with one-to-many relation to another model (Child). The save method of Parent model is overwritten:

```
class ParentModel(models.Model)
    (...)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        (...) # Do sth with the model
        super(ParentModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class ChildModel(models.Model):
    parent= models.ForeignKey(ParentModel)
```

In admin panel multiple Child models objects are displayed using StackedInline on Parent model's page. If a field of parent is edited and saved, the save method is called. When only child's fields are edited, Django do not call the save method of parent (as expected, because nothing changed).

What is the best way to force saving the parent, even if only child was edited (so that my overwritten method does it's stuff)?

Comment: Do you want your method to be called only when editing an inline from the Admin, or whenever your ChildModel is saved?

Comment: It's editable only in admin, so whichever is simpler.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few solutions. Here goes, from simpler to more complex:

You could implement a custom `save` method for `ChildModel` that calls `ParentModel.save`.
You could also connect to your `ChildModel`'s `post_save` or `pre_save` signal.

Now, these two solutions will prove annoying if you're going to update a lot of `ChildModel` instances at once, as you will be calling `ParentModel.save` several times, maybe without purpose.
You might then want to use the following:
Override your `ParentModel`'s `ModelAdmin.change_view` to handle your logic; this is pretty tricky however.

I'm however pretty surprised by the behavior your're encountering, from checking the source, the object should be saved anyway; edited or not.